# numpy boolean comparison between big arrays returns False instead of boolean array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've just encountered the following issues. Starting from two arrays, and performing a boolean comparison like:

```
In [47]: a1 = np.random.randint(0,10,size=1000000)

In [48]: a2 = np.random.randint(0,10,size=1000000)

In [52]: a1[:,None] == a2
Out[52]: False
```

returns a Boolean value instead of an array of booleans, whereas:

```
In [62]: a1 = np.random.randint(0,10,size=10000)

In [63]: a2 = np.random.randint(0,10,size=10000)

In [64]: a1[:,None] == a2
Out[64]: 
array([[False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       ..., 
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ...,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

works as expected. Is this an issue related to the sizes of the arrays? Performing a simple comparison on the single dimension of the array works, no matter the size.

```
In [65]: a1 = np.random.randint(0,10,size=1000000)

In [66]: a2 = np.random.randint(0,10,size=1000000)

In [67]: a1 == a2
Out[67]: array([False, False, False, ..., False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Anyone is able to reproduce the problem? I'm on Numpy 1.9.2 and Python 2.7.3.

EDIT: just update to Numpy 1.11 but the issue persists.

Comment: I am able to reproduce on python 3.4  numpy v1.10.4

Comment: Same behaviour on my computer, python 2.7.10., numpy 1.9.2

Comment: Also note that `a1[:] == a2` or `a1 == a2` do not display this inconsistency.

Comment: What happens with addition or subtraction?  The result uses the same broadcasting.

Comment: Other comparisons (`<`, `>=`, etc.) and arithmetical operations raise `MemoryError` for me. It seems to be just `==` and `!=` that catch this problem and return a boolean value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I try the comparison, I get a warning:

```
[...]/__main__.py:1: DeprecationWarning: elementwise == comparison failed;
this will raise an error in the future.
    if __name__ == '__main__':
```

This warning is triggered in NumPy's code [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/1429c606643d1ad305e710c4a31cb6f398d04c53/numpy/core/src/multiarray/arrayobject.c#L1422):

```C
if (result == NULL) {
    /*
     * Comparisons should raise errors when element-wise comparison
     * is not possible.
     */
    /* 2015-05-14, 1.10 */
    PyErr_Clear();
    if (DEPRECATE("elementwise == comparison failed; "
                  "this will raise an error in the future.") < 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
```

This branch is reached because `result == NULL`, where `result` is what happened when NumPy *tried* to do the requested operation (the elementwise equality check, involving broadcasting two arrays).

Why did this operation fail and return `NULL`? Very possibly because NumPy needed to allocate a *huge* chunk of memory for the array; enough to hold 10<sup>12</sup> booleans. This is about 931 GB: it couldn't do this and returned `NULL` instead.